# Python Unittest - MySQL Hangs if wrong key is entered?

Tags: python, mysql, unit-testing

I have a strange MySQL issue in my unit tests, I do something like below:

```
@patch("myobject.MyObject._some_method")
def test_sync_db(self, mock_m):
    test_data = {
        "id": "1",
        "description": "Some text",
    }

    # Run the code in the test
    myobj = MyObject()
    myobj.some_data = test_data
    myobj.doSomethingWithDb()

    # Read the DB to make sure the correct changes were made
    myobj.db.connect()
    data = myobj.db.read_data(test_data["id"])
    print(data["descriptionn"])
    myobj.db.disconnect()
```

The above code works fine until it reaches the second last line, I have purposely put an additional "n" character on the end, as there is no key matching "descriptionn", I would expect the code to crash.  However, instead the code hangs and MySQL hangs, the entire database table gets screwed up and I have to restart the MySQL server to recover from this.  I can't understand why this happens, the `myobj.db.read_data` is literally just returning a `fetchone()` from a MySQLdb object.

EDIT: As requested, this is effectively what `doSomethingWithDb()` does:

```
def doSomethingWithDb(self):
    self.db.connect()
    for data in self.some_data:
        exists = self.db.read_data(data["id"])
        if exists:
            self.db.update_data(exists)
        else:
            self.db.create_data(exists)
    self.db.disconnect()


EDIT 2: Adding problematic code:
The self.db.read_data method does the following:

    def read_data(self, ...):
        ...
        self.dbcurs.execute(params)
        data = self.dbcurs.fetchone()
        return data


The problem is fixed if I add in `self.dbconn.commit()` immediately after the `data = self.dbcurs.fetchone()` line, not sure why though.  If anyone can explain then I will accept that as an answer.
```

Comment: It's impossible to help without knowing what `MyObject` (and likely especially `myobj.db`) does.

Comment: I explained what myobj.db does at the end, it is a wrapper for MySQLdb extension in Python.  What MyObject does and what MyObject.doSomethingWithDb() is just running some UPDATE queries on the database.  However, I am 100% certain this is irrelevant to this question, the problem is only related with running a select query on the database and then trying to reference an invalid key.

Comment: Instead of restarting the database, just kill your application. You haven't posted any relevant code either. `hangs` could be a live-lock caused because whatever `doSomethingWithDb` or `myobj.db` do, ends up creating transactions that block each other.

Comment: @KillerKode and yet, your app hanged, in a way that's far more likely to be caused by blocking. Post your code, don't describe it. If your `UPDATE` ends up taking locks on an entire table and then you try to `SELECT` anything from it, the code will hang

Comment: Ok I have added it now, from my testing it does not seem to be related to the doSomethingWithDb though.

Comment: How are you dealing with transactions here? It sounds like MySQL is hanging because you don't finish something correctly (when there's an uncaught exception, e.g.)

Comment: Ok I may be wrong, if I comment out the `myobj.doSomethingWithDb()` method in my unit test, it gives me a key error as I would expect, rather than hanging.

Comment: You should probably make `self.db` a context manager and use a `with` block to manage those connections, so uncaught exceptions will cause a transaction rollback and disconnect.

Comment: Do I need to connect and disconnect to the DB for each query? The way the myobj.db class works is by effectively manually connecting once, running a bunch of queries and then manually disconnecting at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your help, both of you.  You guided me to the right direction, it turns out that inside myobj.db.read_access, I am not running a self.dbconn.commit() after running the fetchone query.  Simply adding this immediately after seems to resolve the issues I was facing.

Comment: Have updated the question now, with the fix, however happy to accept anyones answer who can explain why I need the db.commit() to fix this.